# What's up with Outlaw's Den?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've visited Outlaw's Den on Tatooine. It's an open PvP area and according to [an article I've found](http://redrancor.com/forum/news/a-first-look-open-world-pvp-on-tatooine%27s-outlaw%27s-den/) from before the release, it should contain rare gathering nodes and also chests containing commendations.

The place contains no such thing. I didn't find any chests there or gathering nodes. Why is that? Is there any reason to go there now or in the future? (Other than visiting the only GTM kiosk on the planet, while fearing that you are going to be killed while trading.)

Comment: Maybe someone already mined them up / looted the chest? I imagine "rare gathering nodes" and "chests containing commendations" to be somewhat rare and in high demand.

Comment: It would seem that the devs nerfed it: http://www.swtor.com/de/community/showthread.php?t=98999 Dx

Comment: @Resorath, I doubt that. The area was mostly deserted and I didn't see gathering node of any type whatsoever. Clearing all of them would require cooperation between several people, who weren't anywhere nearby (or were hidden).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OLD:

Per the link (provided by [Krazer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/15772/krazer)) to the [official forums](http://www.swtor.com/de/community/showthread.php?t=98999):

> Amending the patch notes: The chests containing commendations and
>   credits in Outlaw's Den have had their respawn timer increased
>   dramatically or respawn at a speed correspondent to the amount of
>   players in Outlaw's Den.
>
> EDIT: Actually these chests have been removed entirely as well as all
>   resource nodes from Outlaw's Den and Ilum.

This apparently was done because of players exploiting the area to grab more high-end resources than the devs were expecting.

Hopefully, they will fix the previous system's exploits and reintroduce loot to the area. But yes, for now the area is only for your own PvP fun. No in-game loot rewards are available in that area at this time.

NEW UPDATE:

As Raven Dreamer pointed out, as of the 1.1 patch released on Jan 18, 2012, the Outlaws' Den (Tatooine) Chests containing Mercenary Commendations are available again.

I have confirmed they do spawn again as of the 1.1 patch. They spawn one at a time. I'm not sure of the exact respawn rate, since there are a handful of easily found spawn locations, but it's around 10 minutes from what I can tell.

They provide a handful of credits and 20 Mercenary Commendations. Probably a random loot item too from time to time.

Comment: As of the 1.1 patch; `The Outlaws' Den (Tatooine)

Chests containing Mercenary Commendations are now available again in the Outlaw's Den.`

Answer (score 1):

I still farm three chest in Outlaw Den each day. When I land on the planet I check WHO. If there are any lvl 50s then figure the chest are already looted and come back the next day. I still get parts of the gear set, weapons, and commendations.